# Problems executing code after Keyboardinterrupt

Tags: python, lcd

I wrote a super simple thingy for this 20x4 LCD screen and I keep on getting this whenever I Interrupt with crtl + c instead of it executing the code I've placed there.
Here's the Error:

```
CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "lcd/clock.py", line 25, in <module>
    sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

and here's the code:

```
import drivers
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
from subprocess import check_output
display = drivers.Lcd()
display.lcd_backlight(0)
IP = check_output(["hostname", "-I"]).split()[0]
usrinpt = input("Text: ")
while len(usrinpt) > 20:
        print("Too Long")
        usrinpt = input("Text: ")
else:
    display.lcd_backlight(1)
    print("Writing to display")
    while True:
        display.lcd_display_string(str(datetime.now().time().strftime("%H:%M:%S")), 1)
        display.lcd_display_string(str(IP), 2)
        display.lcd_display_string(str("____________________"), 3)
        sleep(1)
        display.lcd_display_string(str(datetime.now().time().strftime("%H:%M:%S")), 1)
        display.lcd_display_string(str(IP), 2)
        display.lcd_display_string(str(usrinpt), 3)
        sleep(1)

        if KeyboardInterrupt:
    # If there is a KeyboardInterrupt (when you press ctrl+c), turn off backlights
            display.lcd_backlight(0)
```

Thank you in advance! I think this may be a real simple fix but I'm sadly still a complete novice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `if` statement...

```py
if KeyboardInterrupt:
    # If there is a KeyboardInterrupt (when you press ctrl+c), turn off backlights
    display.lcd_backlight(0)
```

Use the `try / except` statements, which are used to check for errors (Pressing CTRL+C spawns a KeyboardInterrupt error):

```py
try:
    display.lcd_backlight(1)
    print("Writing to display")
    while True:
        display.lcd_display_string(str(datetime.now().time().strftime("%H:%M:%S")), 1)
        display.lcd_display_string(str(IP), 2)
        display.lcd_display_string(str("____________________"), 3)
        sleep(1)
        display.lcd_display_string(str(datetime.now().time().strftime("%H:%M:%S")), 1)
        display.lcd_display_string(str(IP), 2)
        display.lcd_display_string(str(usrinpt), 3)
        sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # If there is a KeyboardInterrupt (when you press ctrl+c), turn off backlights
    display.lcd_backlight(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you pressed Ctrl + C while `sleep(1)` is running. Since you are only checking for a Keyboardinterrupt after the sleep, Python doesn't check for the exception and errors out as normal. You could fix it with a `try... except...`:

```
while True:
    try:
        display.lcd_display_string(str(datetime.now().time().strftime("%H:%M:%S")), 1)
        display.lcd_display_string(str(IP), 2)
        display.lcd_display_string(str("____________________"), 3)
        sleep(1)
        display.lcd_display_string(str(datetime.now().time().strftime("%H:%M:%S")), 1)
        display.lcd_display_string(str(IP), 2)
        display.lcd_display_string(str(usrinpt), 3)
        sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        display.lcd_backlight(0)
```

Here, it will keep on running the code until it encounters a KeyboardInterrupt, where it will execute the `display.lcd_backlight(0)`.